# Apply function to every row in SQL server and perform additional conditions on that row

Tags: sql, t-sql

```
declare @totalBillable decimal(18, 4)
declare @qaTotalMinutes decimal(18, 4)
declare @devTotalMinutes decimal(18, 4)

select * from JobEntry je     
where JobId = 1111
```

So this select will return all job entry records for this particular job.
I need to calculate billable time for every job entry and increment specific value based on the job entry name.
Something like:

```
if je.Name = 'Development'
    set @devTotalMinutes = @devTotalMinutes + dbo.GetBillableTimeMinutesForEntry(je.StartTime, je.EndTime)

if je.Name = 'QA'
    set @qaTotalMinutes = @qaTotalMinutes + dbo.GetBillableTimeMinutesForEntry(je.StartTime, je.EndTime)
```

and so forth.

I need to call **GetBillableTimeMinutesForEntry** function for every entry to calulate billable time between start and end time of the entry.
Then I need to increment one of the *total* variables based on the job entry name.
And repeat for every row.

I know I could use cursors for an iterative approach, but I want to ask if there is a better way to do all this in t-sql.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results *as text tables* in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions for a conditional sum:

```
select je.*,
       sum(case when je.Name = 'Development'
                then dbo.GetBillableTimeMinutesForEntry( je.StartTime, je.EndTime)
                else 0
           end) over (partition by jobid order by je.StartTime) as development_minutes,
       sum(case when je.Name = 'QA'
                then dbo.GetBillableTimeMinutesForEntry( je.StartTime, je.EndTime)
                else 0
           end) over (partition by jobid order by je.StartTime) as qa_minutes
from jobEnty je
```